# Stop Fluent nHibernate from inserting composite key value

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, db2-400

I'm having a problem with Fluent mapping for an iSeries AS400 system. To keep the file using a DDS we are avoiding the use of an auto increment but I can use the timestamp and username as a composite key. My problem is the timestamp is "GENERATED ALWAYS" and the program is trying to insert a NULL. Is there a way I can use the timestamp as part of my composite key but make it so that it's never part of my insert statement?

I left the timestamp expanded in an action since I was playing around but it serves no extra purpose as shown.

```
Public Class InterLog

    Public Overridable Property Username As String
    Public Overridable Property Url As String
    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Timestamp As Date
        Get
            Return _timestamp
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Friend Overridable Property _timestamp As Date

    Public Overloads Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        Return MyBase.Equals(obj)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return MyBase.GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class

Friend Class InterLogMap
    Inherits ClassMap(Of InterLog)

    Public Sub New()
        Table("INTERLOG")
        CompositeId _
            .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.Username, "USERNAME") _
            .KeyProperty(Function(x) x._timestamp, Sub(_set)
                                                       _set.ColumnName("XASTAMP")
                                                   End Sub)

        Map(Function(x) x.Url, "URL")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Really not sure if I do understand... but how could be part of compositeId changing value? Maybe I read it bad... but that seems to be design failure. ID, regardles if composite or not, should be solid, not changing. Maybe that could be the problem with the mapping

Comment: I basically want it to treat the timestamp as an auto increment would be treated in the sense that the timestamp is automatically generated by the DB so the program should not try to insert a value. Does that clear it up any?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i recall CompositeIds are assigned from you always. It is possible to have Ids or properties generated by the database but not part of composite Ids.

Use GuidComb or HighLow as IdGenerator.

If the Username is appwide and not changing then write a custom IdGenerator which gets the username as parameter on initialization and appends a database generated value. For example use TablebasedIdGenerator which uses a table to hold last used id (per username).